# Warning: the -fast option forces static linkage method for the Intel(R) MPI Library

Tags: linker, fortran, mpi, intel-fortran

I am building an MPI Fortran program with Intel's `mpiifort -fast`, something like this:

```
mpiifort -o build/ifort_mkl_mpi_opt/master.o -c -free -extend-source 132 -warn nounused -warn nodeclarations -fast -xHost -module build/ifort_mkl_mpi_opt master.F
```

But am getting this warning:

```
Warning: the -fast option forces static linkage method for the Intel(R) MPI Library.
```

Should I do something about that? If so, what would be the easiest way to make an optimized build without static linking of MPI?

Comment: Why don't you want the library statically linked?  Intel presumably thinks it's worth it to avoid an extra level of indirection through the PLT when calling MPI functions.  https://www.macieira.org/blog/2012/01/sorry-state-of-dynamic-libraries-on-linux/.  If `mpiifort` has an equivalent of gcc's `-fno-plt`, it can make indirect calls directly to library functions, using an address from the GOT.  (e.g. `call [rel function@GOT]` or something like that.)

Comment: @PeterCordes That's true, but Intel apparently also thinks that it's worth a warning...

Comment: So is the point of the warning just to remind you to use it while linking as well?  Maybe it hard-codes some stuff from a specific version of the library, so you need to statically link for correctness.  You're only compiling without linking in the command you show.  **TL:DR: no, you shouldn't do anything about it.**

Comment: @PeterCordes Okay, I'll accept that as an answer. Even better if the warning can be silenced :-)